# Pypy error: RuntimeWarning: C function without declared arguments called, usinc ctypes

Tags: python-2.7, pypy

I'm trying to work with `Pypy`, but as soon as I've executed my code in `Pypy` fails, but with `cPython` works.

I've found several issues googling around regarding ctypes and pypy, but I'm not able to find the error in my code:

```
libc = CDLL("libc.so.6")
ptr = c_void_p(None)
result = libc.getifaddrs(pointer(ptr))
if result:
    return None
ifa = ifaddrs.from_address(ptr.value)
result = {}
```

the code fails at the call `libc.getifaddrs(pointer(ptr))`, returning:

`102: RuntimeWarning: C function without declared arguments called result = libc.getifaddrs(pointer(ptr))`

Any Idea what's going on?

Thanks!

Comment: That warning also exists under CPython, and the code you show qualifies for triggering it. Try explicitly turning on warnings.

Answer (score 0):

just set the argument types of the function and the warning will gone

its considered bad practice not to delcare them anyway

Comment: Hi, could you expand on how to declare them? Thanks!

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#specifying-the-required-argument-types-function-prototypes